# Is there a way to create multiply CKShares with one UICloudSharingController?

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

For now and single sharing I do it like this:

```
//here I have access to record fetched from cloud database
let controller = UICloudSharingController { controller, preparationCompletionHandler in
    let share = CKShare(rootRecord: record)
    share[CKShareTitleKey] = territory.name as CKRecordValue
    share[CKShareTypeKey] = "pl.blueworld.fieldservice" as CKRecordValue
    share.publicPermission = .readWrite

    let operation = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: [record, share], recordIDsToDelete: nil) //what happens if I pass here a three records and three related ckshares?
    operation.savePolicy = .ifServerRecordUnchanged

    operation.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = { records, recordIds, error in
        preparationCompletionHandler(share, CloudAssistant.shared.container, error) //how can I do it for every created ckshare?
    }

    operation.database = territory.database
    CloudAssistant.shared.operationQueue.addOperation(operation)
}
controller.delegate = self
controller.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = self.collaborateBarButtonItem
present(controller, animated: true)
```

But how can I do this for 2 ckshares? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, where you add the `share`, just set up as many as you want, e.g. `let share1 = ...; let share2 = ...;`. Then in the `CKModifyRecordsOperation` initializer, add each of the shares, e.g. `CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: [record1, share1, record2, share2]`.